# bidirectional clipboard can't be shared between VirtualBox and Windows host

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard, bidirectional, virtualbox-guest-additions

I have searched for a solution for days and can't find the right solution for my situation and would like to ask for your help.

I have installed Ubuntu22.04 in the VirtualBox6.1.36 package for Windows 10 host, and the below requests have been done:

1. The GuestAdditions has been installed correctly: vbox_GAs_6.1.36 icon displays correctly and shared folder can be created between VirtualBox and host without a problem.
2. Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack.vbox-extpack-6.1.36a has been installed.
3. Devices-shared clipboard: setting as bidirectional.
4. drag and drop doesn't work either, setting as bidirectional.
5. Copy text from google, then past it to VirtualBox firefox web, doesn't work, then past it to LieberOfficeWriter, doesn't work either.
6. Copy text from Notepad, then past it to VirtualBox, doesn't work.

Any hints would be appreciated, or feel free to question on mentioned steps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing or updating the `virtualbox-guest-x11` and the necessary headers packages and dependencies with `apt`.

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
```

Then, run the following command and restart your VM to enable clipboard:

```bash
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Comment: Thanks. Have tried your suggestions, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on my machine (Debian guest Windows host).

What solved it for me was re-running the install from the GuestAdditions disk image.

First, make sure that you already are using the Guest Additions by clicking devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image.
If it looks like the CD is already in, and it still isn't working, try the steps listed here (these are basically identical to the steps for Debian):

https://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-ubuntu/

*I ignored the "Install Guest Additions" part because it didn't work*

In the Debian version that I used, Step 7 involves `mount /media/cdrom` which is missing from the Ubuntu instructions.

After you have re-installed the modules from the disk, reboot. This fixed it for me so I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try to look in this link:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=313161

this command solved my problem:

```
apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe
```